# Importing Library into iTunes through Windows SDK (Python)

Tags: python, windows, itunes, win32com

I am using the Windows COM SDK for python in order to manipulate iTunes.

I would like to know if there is a way to import a new library in iTunes. The user is able to do that ("MenuBar>File>Library>Import list..."), but is it possible with the SDK?

I've already looked into the documentation, but I haven't seen anything. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. keep checking the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use `xml.etree.ElementTree` module to generate a iTunes `xml` file:

```
 C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Music\iTunes\iTunes Music Library.xml
```